# Spring Boot 2.4.1 disappeared too soon from documentation

Tags: spring-boot

My team has just upgraded from SpringBoot 1.5.12.RELEASE to 2.4.1 but only to discover that a few days after this major upgrade the documentation references for 2.4.1 have suspiciously and unexpectedly vanished from the documentation page at https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn

We cannot afford that frequent upgrades.

The current GA release is 2.4.2

Why did 2.4.1 disappear?

Was there something fundamentally wrong with 2.4.1 that we should be aware of?

Is there a release plan we can follow going forward?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks, I know the documentation pages are archived and so I can always recover documentation for any previous version.
The disappearance of 2.4.1 though was been quite unexpected. I just feared there was something fundamentally wrong with the the 2.4.1 release for it to disappear so quickly.

Comment: I got it, You may check 2.4.2 release notes https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.4.2 to double check

Comment: The Spring project pages only list the most recent patch versions. All released versions are still available in Maven Central (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent). Nothing has disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, I know everything is archived and not permanently lost.
Like I said, I only wondered about early disappearance of references from documentation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Spring project pages only list the most recent patch versions.

I believe this answers my question.